# Relate CSS variables to each other in context

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-variables

Background: trying to create an element for easily embedding `Font Awesome 5.10.2` `Duotone` icons into any piece of `HTML`.

This icon element uses `HTML` attributes which should map to a specific icon where the mapping is purely controlled by the `CSS` author.

```
<x pay></x> <!-- <- icon value for pay should be customizable by CSS author -->
```

Below is my solution but I wonder ...

---

Can one reduce

```
x {
  position: relative; 
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: var(--fa-5-d);
  font-weight: var(--fa-d);
  background: var(--x-background);
  line-height: 1em !important;
}
x::after { position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; }
x::before { color: var(--fa-primary-color,   inherit); opacity: 1; opacity: var(--fa-primary-opacity,   1.0); }
x::after  { color: var(--fa-secondary-color, inherit);             opacity: var(--fa-secondary-opacity, 0.4); }
```

```
x:before { --fa-credit-card:   "\f09d"; }
x:after  { --fa-credit-card: "\10f09d"; }
```

```
<x pay></x>
```

this ↓

```
x[pay]:before,
x[pay]:after { content: var(--fa-credit-card); }
```

to this ↓ (avoiding `x[pay]:before, x[pay]:after` repetition)

```
x[pay] { --content: var(--fa-credit-card); }
```

in essence

- set a `CSS` variable once on a parent to a value `v`
- that diverges into different child values `v₁` and `v₂` related to `v`?

?

Comment: “Diverge into different child values” how exactly?

Comment: set `--fa-credit-card` once and have it evaluate in `:before` to `"\f09d"` in `:after` to `"\10f09d"`

Comment: I meant in general … will it always be `10` added in as an (almost-) prefix, or …?

Comment: For this particular case, `10` is always added, yes. The `"\"` prefix caused complications with string concatenation when I tried that though. Both *always add `10`*-based and general solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don’t think string concatenation can work here - \ and `f09d` concatenated after another, aren’t interpreted to have the same _meaning_, as `\f09d` “in one piece” in the first place.

Comment: Is there a way to use `calc`?

Comment: Don’t think so, MDN says _“[calc] can be used anywhere a <length>, <frequency>, <angle>, <time>, <percentage>, <number>, or <integer> is allowed.”_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A convenience improvement using web components / custom elements:

```html
<link  href='//cdn.blue/{fa-5.10.2}/css/all.css' rel=stylesheet>
<link  href='//cdn.blue/{fa+}/var.css' rel=stylesheet>
<link  href='//cdn.blue/{fa+}/x-i.css' rel=stylesheet>
<script src='//cdn.blue/<shin>/shin-element.js'></script>

<script>
class XI extends ShinElement {
  constructor() { 
    super(`<style></style>`);
    ShinElement.IPA(this, 'jsUpdate', { a: 'js-update', t: ShinElement.Number0 });
  }
  connectedCallback() { XI.css(this); }
  static css(t) {
    const c =   getComputedStyle(t);
    const i = c.getPropertyValue('--i').trim();
    const s = t._.QS("style");
          s.textContent = `:host:before, :host:after { content: var(${i}); }`;
  }
  static get observedAttributes() { return [ 'js-update' ]; }
  attributeChangedCallback(a, o, n) {
    switch (a) {
      case "js-update":
        const u =  this.jsUpdate;
        if (u > 0) this._jsu = setInterval(XI.css, u, this);
        else { clearInterval(this._jsu); delete this._jsu; }
        break;
    }
  }
}
XI.define();
</script>

<style>x-i[pay] { --i: --fa-user-edit; }</style>

      <x-i pay js-update=200 id=x></x-i>
```

- [https://cdn.blue/<shin>/docs/ShinElement.html](https://cdn.blue/%3Cshin%3E/docs/ShinElement.html)
- https://codepen.io/cetinsert/pen/QWLZgwZ?editors=1000

---

The need for `js-update` (`HTML`), `jsUpdate` (`JS`) for doing live `CSS` edits is unfortunate.

```
x.jsUpdate = 0; // to disable getComputedStyle updates
```

Thus I still wonder if there is a better solution - be it `CSS`-only or using web components.